# Help! Stuck on Ubuntu 20.10 can't upgrade

Tags: 20.10

I have a VM with a ton of stuff on it, and I shut it down for about a year. It's Ubuntu 20.10, so yeah it's not a LTS release. It looks like all the groovy packages have been removed from the official repos, so Software Updater can't install anything.

Is there anyway I can upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 now?

Comment: Do you want to upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.10 or just upgrade (`apt upgrade`)?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 *release-upgraded* to 21.04; so your upgrade path disappeared with 21.04 went EOL.  You can *upgrade via reinstall* desktop systems, but as system directories are wiped during the install; many server apps will have configs lost - ie. it's for desktop systems. But in future you should use LTS releases if you don't plan on *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  (20.10 = 2020-October; so remembering the month you need to upgrade before isn't very hard)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *The EOLUPgrades link maybe useful; but alas you've missed the window to go to 21.04*  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/